# Omni-Riley-Rebuses

Tags: word, wordplay, rebus

> Partially inspired by MetaZen’s Four Directions Series :)

North:

> [image]

East:

> [image]

South:

> [image]

West:

> [image]

<sub>This puzzle is a part of [Ooohh, it all makes sense now! :D](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/85613/ooohh-it-all-makes-sense-now-d)</sub>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is

> GERMANIUM.

To the north we have

> SIL+LIC+ON (SIL is second half of BRASIL, ON is ONE minus E);

to the east we have

> ARS+ENI+C (ARS is the ISO 4217 code for the Argentinian peso);

to the south we have

> TI+I(G)+N (T.I., left half of one version of Instagram logo; nitrogen);

to the west we have

> GAL + LI + IUM (one gal is 1 cm/s^2, a unit I'd never heard of before; we need the A because the second picture appears to be of lithium floating in oil).

And

> in between these in the periodic table we find GERMANIUM.

Comment: gotcha, but will only award check once you solved all the rebuses :) there is only one choice for east, find out why. for south, it is not ice-T. second one is indeed half an icon. for south, it is not aluminium, there is another way out.

Comment: Ah, OK. I found the guy on the left in the end.

Comment: [the remaining little bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gal_(unit))

Comment: Good grief. I had absolutely no idea that existed. Today I learned something.